# SQL - select * given count from another table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to `select * from` two tables (`a` and `b`) using a join (`column a.id and b.id`), given that the count of a column (`b.owner`) in b is lower than 3, i.e. the occurence of a person's name can be max 2.

I've tried:

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.owner) AS b_count

FROM a LEFT JOIN b on a.id = b.id

GROUP BY b.owner HAVING COUNT(b_count) <3
```

As im pretty new to SQL, im pretty stuck here. How can i resolve this issue? The result should be all columns for owners who do not appear more than twice in the data.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you are trying to run is not working due to the columns missing in the [GROUP BY clause](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-group-by/).

As you are outputting all columns from table `a` (with `SELECT a.*`), you need to include all those columns in the `GROUP BY` statement, so that the database understand the group of fields to group by and perform the aggregation required (in your case `COUNT(b.owner)`).

### Example

Considering that your table `a` has 3 columns below:

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
  id INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  birthday DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

.. and your table `b` the following and referencing the first table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
  id INTEGER,
  person_id INTEGER,
  sale_value DECIMAL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES persons(id)
);
```

.. you should query it aggregating the `COUNT()` by those 3 columns:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.birthday, COUNT(b.person_id) AS b_count
  FROM persons a 
  LEFT JOIN sales b ON a.id = b.person_id
 GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.birthday
HAVING COUNT(b.person_id) < 3
```

### Alternative

In case the total of records on the 2nd table is not important to you, you could use a different "strategy" here to avoid performing the `JOIN` between the tables (useful when joining two huge tables) and rewriting all the columns from `a` on the `SELECT`+`GROUP BY`.
By identifying the records that has less than the 3 occurrences firstly:

```
SELECT b.person_id
  FROM sales b
 GROUP BY b.person_id
HAVING COUNT(b.id) < 3;
```

.. and using it in the `WHERE` clause to retrieve all the columns from the 1st table only for the ids that resulted from the previous query:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM persons a
 WHERE a.id IN (....other query here....);
```

.. the execution happens in a more chronological and, perhaps, easier way to visualize while getting more familiar with SQL:

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM persons a
 WHERE a.id IN (SELECT b.person_id
                  FROM sales b
                 GROUP BY b.person_id
                HAVING COUNT(b.id) < 3);
```

DB Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8CA7wM8aKjLjjVSCiwUVPP/1)

Comment: Your last Alternative is what im looking for. But how can also include all colums from table b?

Comment: That is not possible! As written in the answer, if you need any column to be printed in the final query, you need to go through the Join + Aggregation approach.

Answer (score 1):

In Standard SQL, you can use:

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.owner) AS b_count
FROM a LEFT JOIN
     b 
     ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(b.owner) < 3;
```

This may not work in all databases (and it assumes that `a.id` is unique/primary key).  An alternative would be to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM b 
              WHERE a.id = b.id
             ) as b_count
      FROM a 
     ) a
WHERE b_count < 3;
```

Comment: I've tried the following:

SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.egn) AS b_count

FROM woza as a LEFT JOIN

     woze as b

     on a.id = b.id

GROUP BY a.id

HAVING COUNT(b.egn) < 3;

However, it did not work. Do you know what could be the issue?

Comment: @E.vanDongen . . . I think the answer explains that.  The first query won't work in all databases (and you still have not tagged the database you are using).  You can use the second version.